# Test class for schedulable interface

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can i test this class?

```
global class CustomerPortalRevokeSchedulable implements Schedulable {
    
    global void execute(SchedulableContext c)
    {   
        CustomerPortalRevokeBatch theC = new CustomerPortalRevokeBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(theC);                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

To test a `schedulable`, schedule a run in your test method using `system.schedule()`, and wrap that call in `test.startTest()` and `test.stopTest()` calls.  This will ensure that the scheduled job is finished when `test.stopTest()` completes and the next line of code runs.  See [Testing the Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm#apex_scheduler_testing) in the Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide for a full explanation and sample code.

**EDIT**: to clarify a point I should have made to begin with:  your `scheduleable` class *will not execute* until `test.stopTest()` runs.  Any assertions before `test.stopTest()` are testing the initial state; any assertions of your class's actual behavior (e.g., querying to confirm expected changes) must occur after `test.stopTest`

Answer (score 15):

It may not be considered best practice, but I find with batch and schedulable classes it's way  easier to just run the methods inside them manually, and this also lets you run several in a test and check the results of the runs without running into difficulty:

```
SchedulableContext sc = null;
TheScheduleableClass tsc = new TheScheduleableClass();
tsc.execute(sc);
```

Comment: That's not the best practice, or even the recommended practice. The other answers here are correct, while this one is not.

Comment: Hey, I said it wasn't the best way to do it ;) To my mind though it still tests the functionality of the class; I don't feel the need to test that the system scheduler will fire it or not when I know it works from manual testing. These methods should compliment manual tests, not replace them.

Comment: Actually, the point of **test methods** is to *replace* manual testing. In theory, developers should be able to change their production code and verify that the changes do not break the intended logic, without manual testing. Anyone not using proper test methods will spend up to 1000% more time testing their code manually.

Comment: While it's true that not all code can be tested automatically, those should be limited to as few cases as possible. Since we have a *correct* method for testing scheduled classes, we should use those proper methods. They are documented and work perfectly.

Comment: I fell into this habit when needing to run different async jobs in a specific order which wasn't practical in tests. Anyway, this could easily become a lengthy discussion so time to stop I think :)

Comment: I'm not going to cover fringe cases. Like you said, it could take a while. However, like any good developer, I'm always going to recommend the method that the platform developers themselves recommend and have designed the system for. If, in some future release, the SC parameter has some use, then this method of testing won't work. Best to avoid the habit to begin with.

Comment: This is pretty much the only way to test a scheduled callout. See also [testing future with callout from schedulable class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108765/testing-future-with-callout-from-schedulable-class)

Comment: There was a lot of back and forth on the nature of testing here, but can someone say ***why*** this is a bad way to do it?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think this post was very useful. Its definitely not in the spirit of Salesforce and unit testing philosophy per se but it does get the job done when you want coverage quickly. The more tools I have to accomplish a job the better. On an aside sfdcfox can't tell you how many times your posts have helped me out. Thanks both of you for posting to the community and sharing.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this answer. I write tests for my code. Why test the scheduler? This is how it would be done in any sane environment _outside_ of Salesforce.

Comment: I think it is totally appropriate. It lets you test the logic within the execute method of the class. It's not our responsibility to ensure the Salesforce scheduling mechanism works.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want code coverage for this scheduled class then you can do something like below, but you still should have a test method that tests the logic for your batch class as well.

```
@isTest
private class myTestClass {

    static testMethod void myTestMethod() {        
         test.starttest();
         CustomerPortalRevokeSchedulable myClass = new CustomerPortalRevokeSchedulable ();   
         String chron = '0 0 23 * * ?';        
         system.schedule('Test Sched', chron, myClass);
         test.stopTest();
    }
}
```