# testing future with callout from schedulable class

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex, callout, future

I'm definitely missing something.
 How do I test Schedulable class with a future method that does a callout?
I have 100% code coverage of the Schedulable class but 0% of my service.The test fails as no Error_Log__c object is inserted.
How should I test it correctly?

1) A schedulable class

```
public class  RemoteErrorsBatch implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
         RemoteErrorsServiceImpl.processConnectFailures(); 
    }
}
```

2) A service with SOAP callout

```
@future(callout = true)
public static void processConnectFailures(){
    RemoteSystemFailure[] lFailures = RemoteErrorsServiceImpl.getRemoteSystemFailure();
    List<Error_Log__c> lErrors = new List<Error_Log__c> ();
    for(RemoteSystemFailure oFailure  : lFailures){
        lErrors.add(new Error_Log__c( Description__c = oFailure.msg);
    }
    insert lErrors;
}
```

3) A failing test class

```
Test.startTest();
Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new RemoteErrorsBatchTest.RemoteErrorsMockImpl());
String CRON_EXP = '0 00 * * * ?';
String jobId = System.schedule('RemoteErrorsBatch',CRON_EXP,new RemoteErrorsBatch());
Test.stopTest();
List<Error_Log__c> lErrors  = [SELECT Description__c FROM Error_Log__c];
System.assertEquals(1, lErrors.size());
```

Answer (score 4):

I tend to break this up into two testmethods

1. Test the construction of `RemoteErrorsBatch` and invocation of `execute()`. This is really just code coverage as you can guarantee that SFDC will invoke the execute() method at the appointed time so you don't have to assert that this will happen.
2. Test the invocation of static method `RemoteErrorsServiceImpl.processConnectFailures()`.  In this second testmethod, you will use your `Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new RemoteErrorsBatchTest.RemoteErrorsMockImpl());`

The mock class needs to return a list of mocked `RemoteSystemFailure` objects.

Comment: That's my current approach :/ I hopped there would be a way to test differently

Comment: you could try instantiating the schedulable class, and then , within a `Test.startTest() ... Test.stopTest()` bracket, invoke the schedulable's `execute()`